# Performing between operation on documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we perform a between query within multiple documents?
For eg:

consider document1. There is message field in this document which says "Call initialised".
Consider document 2. There is a message field which says "Call started".
Consider document 3. There is a message field which says "Call ended".

Now I want to search between "Call Initialised " and "Call end" messages which should fetch me all messages between these two messages.

Range query on timestamp is not possible, as I have 1000 records for the same timestamp.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: You could add another discrete `event_code` field for each event, e.g. "0" would be "Call initialised", "1" would mean "Call started", and "2" would be "Call ended". Then you could do a range query to get all documents where `event_code` is between 0 and 2.

Comment: Thanks. :) I was actually looking for an option without be being able to insert data again. Is there no way to fetch data maintaining the insertion order?

Comment: There's no concept of insertion order in ES, except if you already have a sequential primary key id field that you can count on. It's a good idea to think hard about what data you'll need before starting to index your documents.

Comment: Yeah right. I guess I will have to add a tag for each event while inserting, or maintain an incremental id in each document to suffice my requirement.